# Images not loading after AWS deployment

Tags: jquery, angular, amazon-web-services, deployment, image-gallery

There are a few images that are triggering errors.

> Cannot GET /images/projects/mvp/mvp-2-1.png

HTML (just the start of the gallery):

```
<div id="etch" class="container-fluid white padding buffer" ng-controller="GalleryCtrl">
  <div class="auto" data-featherlight-gallery data-featherlight-filter="a">
    <a class="gallery img-tile" href="/images/designer/super-turtle-etch.jpeg">
        <img src="/images/designer/super-turtle-etch.jpeg" class="buffer-img center-cropped-b" alt="Super Turtle Etch"/>
    </a>
    <a class="gallery img-tile" href="./images/designer/stf-1.jpg">
        <img src="./images/designer/stf-1.jpg" class="buffer-img center-cropped-b" alt="Trace: She's the First*{UTK}"/>
    </a>
    <a class="gallery img-tile" href="/images/designer/stf-2.jpg">
        <img src="/images/designer/stf-2.jpg" class="buffer-img center-cropped-b" alt="Trace: She's the First*{UTK}"/>
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

The 1st image works perfectly well, but the 2nd and 3rd do not. I added the ./ to try out, and it isn't working as well. /images/ isn't working either.

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers', [])      
.controller('GalleryCtrl', function($scope){
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.gallery').featherlightGallery();
    });
    $.featherlightGallery.prototype.afterContent = function() {
        var caption = this.$currentTarget.find('img').attr('alt');
        this.$instance.find('.caption').remove();
        $('<div class="caption" style="margin-bottom: 10px">').text(caption).appendTo(this.$instance.find('.featherlight-content'));
      }
      $('a.gallery').featherlightGallery({
        previousIcon: '&#9664;',     /* Code that is used as previous icon */
        nextIcon: '&#9654;',         /* Code that is used as next icon */
        galleryFadeIn: 100,          /* fadeIn speed when slide is loaded */
        galleryFadeOut: 100          /* fadeOut speed before slide is loaded */
    });
  });
```

I checked case-sensitivity as well. It doesn't seem to work any differently. Out of less than 75 images, only about 9 of them aren't working. There doesn't seem to be a connection I can find (like image size).

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: The second and third ones have .jpg extensions, the first *.jpg. Could've be that the issue, event though it's the same thing? What are the other 'failing' images extensions?

Comment: @Vega Are you saying the extension could be causing the issue? I haven't thought of that. The other extension is .png. For both, I have working (.jpg and .png) images. It seems to be these selected ones. Would a site url help?

Comment: Yes, I was thinking that the extensions are causing the issue. is there a way you can  convert *jpeg to *.jpg before processing?

Comment: @xtianpoop did you solve this?

Comment: @User-801771 I used an image converter only on the files that didn't load, changing the 5 .jpeg to .jpg files and the 8 .png to .jpg files, and it worked! I have other .png and .jpeg files that seem to be fine currently. I'm not sure why these select files decided to not work, but converting the format seemed to solve the problem for now.